# Bundler and RubyGems global config to download all gems to local folder

Tags: rubygems, bundler, offline

I want to download lot of gems and bundle installs to directory in my computer (for example - ~/gems_cache) and then copy this folder and install the gems in a compute with no internet acces.

I know I can do bundle package and gem fetch, but It will be much easier if there is a configuration that will say bundler and rubygems to download all gems to those folder, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've run `bundle package` once, Bundler will keep the `vendor/cache` directory up to date whenever you run `bundle install`. On the disconnected computer, you can run `bundle install --local` to install the gems from `vendor/cache`.

If you want to copy the installed gems, run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`. Bundler will install all of your gems into the `vendor/bundle` subdirectory of your project. You can substitute any path you prefer.

Note that if you have gems that compile platform-specific code (such as C libraries), you'll need to package and install on the same platform as your target computer.

The best article I've seen on this is Steve Klabnik's [How to not rely on Rubgems.org for deployment](http://words.steveklabnik.com/how-to-not-rely-on-rubygemsorg-for-deployment). He recommends a slightly different approach, but describes the different options and tradeoffs very well.